# Broken image URL

Tags: images, urls, errors

I seem to be having a problem with broken URL links in posts for images. If you click on the image from the post you will see the URL but if you try to then copy and paste that URL it will show as a broken link.

Here is a test page I put together to try and figure this out:
http://www.sixteeneighteen.co.uk/2013/04/work/

If you click on the image it'll show the url as http://www.sixteeneighteen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/remove01.jpg

but if you then try to refresh this page or copy and paste the link it won't show I've been playing with file permissions and that doesn't seem to do anything they are set to 755

I've looked everywhere online for something similar but can't seem to find any answers, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Its working for me http://www.sixteeneighteen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/remove01.jpg

Comment: Its working fine for me. Kindly clear the cache by ctrl+f5 and check it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. http://www.sixteeneighteen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/remove01.jpg
i dont see any problem with the link.